# Data and Models in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have this WebApp with this HTML layout

Nav-column-|  Center Column----   |  Right Column

Link1---------|Data corresponding|Data Corresponding to Link1-A

Link2---------|  to Nav-column------|  (ie based oon Center Column Link)

Link3---------| Link1-A--------------|

----------------|   Link1-B-------------          |

I want to fully use AngularJS' strengths. I have separated the three columns are **three different views**, with Nav-column being loaded on page load. Now, I want to change the **MODEL/DATA** being displayed in the center column based on the link user clicks on the nav-column. How do I do that?

I understand that I dont need to change the view(which is stupid, I think). I need to change the data only.

Comment: put a watch on $location.path() and do what you want to do

Comment: Sounds like you should broadcast an event between controllers when the user clicks on nav-column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to a look to this great blog post proposing a solution for nesting views and routing. You will find a complete solution to manage views using `ng-switch`and `ng-include` similar to what Benoit Tremblay is saying.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm

Comment: Yeah i Saw this post. Didn't understand a lot of it! Am very new to AngularJS. Do you have other links too? Maybe some working example somewhere or plunkr?

Comment: You should take a look at this : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

It is pretty much the same concept but developped for angularui and it has a great sample.

Comment: Frank6 I am using that right now, but how do I change the data there? I can create multiple views, nested views etc, but how do I make the data in a view change?

Comment: Is it data that you need to load or data that you already have ? Have you try using the scope to change data `scope.data`. Did you take a look at the resolve method to resolve any asynchronous controller dependencies ? Can post a bit of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much two options:

1. You use ng-show and a scope variable shared between your views. (your center view will become clutter if you have a lot of stuff, great if you don't have too much going on)
2. You use a clean ng-include and a scope variable with the view you want to show. Great if you have a lot of possibilities.

Or you can mix both if you want to group some of them. It's totally up to what you need.